# Pandas: How to use list variable in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`:

```
state   name    age
WB      Jim     26
CA      John    32
CA      Jason   14
```

where I am trying to use `groupby` **state,name** and and find `max()` of **age**:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['state', 'name'])['age'].max().reset_index()
```

The above is working, but when I use a list variable instead of hardcoding column names like:

```
cols = ['state', 'name']
df2 = df.groupby(cols)['age'].max().reset_index()
```

I am getting error:

```
raise TypeError("You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'")
TypeError: You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cols = ['state', 'name']
df2 = df.groupby([*cols])['age'].max().reset_index()
```

This creates a copy of cols by [unpacking](https://In%20this%20modified%20code,%20each%20request%20is%20executed%20concurrently%20within%20a%20single%20event%20loop%20using%20asyncio.gather().%20The%20ClientSession%20is%20created%20once%20within%20the%20context%20of%20api_pool_uploader()%20and%20passed%20to%20the%20execute_request()%20coroutine%20for%20each%20request.%20%20By%20using%20a%20single%20event%20loop%20and%20concurrent%20execution,%20you%20avoid%20the%20issues%20with%20pickling%20ClientSession%20instances%20and%20improve%20the%20efficiency%20of%20your%20requests.) into a new list and doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the chatgpt policy and i'll not do it again.

Comment: No problem, you're previous answers are excellent so you can probably just improve your current ones.